# Mockito : doAnswer Vs thenReturn

Tags: java, mockito

I am using Mockito for service later unit testing. I am confused when to use `doAnswer` vs `thenReturn`.

Can anyone help me in detail? So far, I have tried it with `thenReturn`.

Answer (score 237):

You should use `thenReturn` or `doReturn` when you know the return value at the time you mock a method call. This defined value is returned when you invoke the mocked method.

> `thenReturn(T value)` Sets a return value to be returned when the method is called.

```java
@Test
public void test_return() throws Exception {
    Dummy dummy = mock(Dummy.class);
    int returnValue = 5;

    // choose your preferred way
    when(dummy.stringLength("dummy")).thenReturn(returnValue);
    doReturn(returnValue).when(dummy).stringLength("dummy");
}
```

`Answer` is used when you need to do additional actions when a mocked method is invoked, e.g. when you need to compute the return value based on the parameters of this method call.

> Use `doAnswer()` when you want to stub a void method with generic `Answer`.
>
> Answer specifies an action that is executed and a return value that is returned when you interact with the mock.

```java
@Test
public void test_answer() throws Exception {
    Dummy dummy = mock(Dummy.class);
    Answer<Integer> answer = new Answer<Integer>() {
        public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            String string = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
            return string.length() * 2;
        }
    };

    // choose your preferred way
    when(dummy.stringLength("dummy")).thenAnswer(answer);
    doAnswer(answer).when(dummy).stringLength("dummy");
}
```

Comment: hi @Roland Weisleder but sometimes you should return some value generated inner  code and nothing to do with arguments, e.g. `code = UUID.randomUUID()`, I found impossible to implement this with `mockito`.

Comment: When your mock should return a new UUID for each invocation you would implement the `Answer` just with `return UUID.randomUUID();`.

Comment: Can I take this method from new Answer initialization ant put it in some method, to make the code a little more cleaner?

Comment: @Line `Answer` is a functional interface, so with Java 8 you could replace it with a lambda expression. If the isn't clean enough any other usual and unusual refactoring is possible.

Comment: @ zhuguowei: return some value generated inner code? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 61):

`doAnswer` and `thenReturn` do the same thing if:

1. You are using Mock, not Spy
2. The method you're stubbing is returning a value, not a void method.

Let's mock this BookService

```
public interface BookService {
    String getAuthor();
    void queryBookTitle(BookServiceCallback callback);
}
```

You can stub getAuthor() using `doAnswer` and `thenReturn`.

```
BookService service = mock(BookService.class);
when(service.getAuthor()).thenReturn("Joshua");
// or..
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return "Joshua";
    }
}).when(service).getAuthor();
```

Note that when using `doAnswer`, you can't pass a method on `when`.

```
// Will throw UnfinishedStubbingException
doAnswer(invocation -> "Joshua").when(service.getAuthor());
```

So, when would you use `doAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`? I can think of two use cases:

1. When you want to "stub" void method.

Using doAnswer you can do some additionals actions upon method invocation. For example, trigger a callback on queryBookTitle.

```
BookServiceCallback callback = new BookServiceCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String bookTitle) {
        assertEquals("Effective Java", bookTitle);
    }
};
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        BookServiceCallback callback = (BookServiceCallback) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        callback.onSuccess("Effective Java");
        // return null because queryBookTitle is void
        return null;
    }
}).when(service).queryBookTitle(callback);
service.queryBookTitle(callback);
```

2. When you are using Spy instead of Mock

When using when-thenReturn on Spy Mockito will call real method and then stub your answer. This can cause a problem if you don't want to call real method, like in this sample:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);
// Will throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("java");
assertEquals("java", spy.get(0));
```

Using doAnswer we can stub it safely.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);
doAnswer(invocation -> "java").when(spy).get(0);
assertEquals("java", spy.get(0));
```

Actually, if you don't want to do additional actions upon method invocation, you can just use `doReturn`.

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);
doReturn("java").when(spy).get(0);
assertEquals("java", spy.get(0));
```

Comment: what if the mocked method is void?

Comment: Igor, that's exactly where doAnswer() comes into picture and he has covered that in the answer above.

Comment: When using `doAnswer(new Answer() { ... return null;}` i get a warning in eclipse for "Answer is a raw type. References to generic type Answer<T> should be parameterized". Is there a way to resolve this (except ignoring the warning ofc)?

Comment: Note that when using doAnswer, you can't pass a method on when --> this line saved me, thanks

Answer (score 15):

The simplest answer is:

- If you need a fixed return value on method call then we should use **thenReturn(…)**
- If you need to perform some operation or the value need to be computed at run time then we should use **thenAnswer(…)**

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this question when I was trying to figure out how to solve my particular problem.

It was how to perfor an operation on a passed-in parameter to a Java function in Mockito, where the function in question also returns a value.

I got really confused with the syntax until I finally figured it out.

Pasting my sample code here in case it helps me again in the future.

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

// See https://www.baeldung.com/java-holder-class for how to do "pass-by-ref" in Java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Holder<T> {
    T value;
}

class MyClass {
    public String doTwoThings(Holder<String> input) {
        // changes pass-by-ref input value
        input.value += " some extra text at the end";
        // returns another value
        return "whatever";
    }
}

class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    void doTwoThingsOnAMock() {
        // arrange
        var myClassMock = mock(MyClass.class);
        var input = new Holder<>("My input");
        when(myClassMock.doTwoThings(input))
            .thenAnswer(
                invocationOnMock -> {
                    Holder<String> input2 = invocationOnMock.getArgument (0);
                    input2.setValue("Something else was set by Mockito!");
                    return "return value set by Mockito!";
                }
            );

        // act
        var output = myClassMock.doTwoThings(input);

        // assert
        assertEquals("return value set by Mockito!", output);
        assertEquals("Something else was set by Mockito!", input.value);
    }

    @Test
    void doTwoThingsOnAReal() {
        // arrange
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        var input = new Holder<>("My input");

        // act
        var output = myClass.doTwoThings(input);

        // assert
        assertEquals("whatever", output);
        assertEquals("My input some extra text at the end", input.value);
    }
}
```