# Printing statements in thenReturn of mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock a certain class while writing my test cases.

Is there a way to print some statements before returning a value? Like:

```
when(x.callFunction(10).thenReturn(new String("Hello"));
```

The above statement works, however I am not able to do the following:

```
when(x.callFunction(10).thenReturn({
   System.out.println("Mock called---going to return hello");
   return new String("Hello");});
```

Comment: You got good answers, but: don't spend too much time on stuff like this. If you *think* you need such print statements to be able to understand what your code is doing, then my gut feeling is that you might have a "quality" problem with either your production or your test code. So, this might be worth stepping back and talking with some experienced folks about the things you are doing.

Comment: @GhostCat I will be using thenReturn in my final code. This is more to test my testing code and check if my mocking function is being called or not! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `thenAnswer` you can execute additional actions every time the mocked method is invoked.

```
when(x.callFunction(10)).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)  {
        System.out.println("Mock called---going to return hello");
        return "Hello";
    }
});
```

See also [thenAnswer Vs thenReturn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36627077/4365460).

Comment: I get an error cannot find symbol Answer. I imported org.Mockito.Answers

Comment: import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

Answer (score 3):

If the object you're going to create is not `final`, then besides `thenAnswer` provided by @Roland Weisleder, you can just use an anonymous subclass with init block in `thenReturn`, like the following example code:

```
class FoobarFactory {
    public Foobar buildFoobar() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Foobar {
    private String name;
    public Foobar(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

with mock code as:

```
@Test
public void testFoobar() throws Exception {
    FoobarFactory foobarFactory = mock(FoobarFactory.class);
    when(foobarFactory.buildFoobar()).thenReturn(new Foobar("somename") {
        {
            System.out.println("Creating mocked Foobar");
        }
    });

    Foobar foobar = foobarFactory.buildFoobar();
    assertThat(foobar.getName(), is("somename"));
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. But more on the "code puzzle" side of things. I wouldn't want something like that in our unit tests ...

Comment: Yes,  `thenAnswer` will always be a better practice, just post it here to share a possibility :-)

Comment: Funny thing; I thought further about this; and put up a completely different answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I like the other answers, but given your latest comment:

*I will be using thenReturn in my final code. This is more to test my testing code and check if my mocking function is being called or not!*

I have another idea for you: do not return/print on that call; use `thenThrow()` instead!

The point is: print statements in the console are sometimes helpful; but they are easy to be overlooked. If the whole purpose is to be sure that a certain call happens on a certain mock; then just throw an exception instead of returning a value. As JUnit will give you direct and hard-to-ignore feedback on that; by failing the testcase.

You could even go one step further and put up @expected on that test - in that way you have a method to test this aspect automatically - if the mock isn't called; no exception; test will fail.

Comment: Agree with "do not print to console in UT", it'll be always ignored.