# Mock external dependency that returns a Future of list

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a class which have external dependency that returns future of lists.
How to mock the external dependency?

```
 public void meth() {
     //some stuff
     Future<List<String>> f1 = obj.methNew("anyString")
     //some stuff
 }

 when(obj.methNew(anyString()).thenReturn("how to intialise some data here, like list of names")
```

Comment: Maybe `thenAnswer` is what you need here instead of `thenReturn`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36627077/1744230) explains the difference between those two.

Comment: Can u elaborate more

Answer (score 26):

You can create the future and return it using `thenReturn()`. In the case below, I create an already completed `Future<List<String>>` using `CompletableFuture`.

```
when(f1.methNew(anyString()))
        .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C")));
```

Comment: Similarly, how o return for  Call<A> call = obji.methNew(B).

Answer (score 13):

As alternative way you may mock the Future as well. The benefit of such way is ability to define any behavior.

For example you want to test a case when a task was canceled:

```
final Future<List<String>> mockedFuture = Mockito.mock(Future.class);
when(mockedFuture.isCancelled()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
when(mockedFuture.get()).thenReturn(asList("A", "B", "C"));

when(obj.methNew(anyString()).thenReturn(mockedFuture);
```