# How to return different results when calling the same mocked method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that I call that connects to another server and each time I call it, and it returns different data.
I am writing a unit test for the class calling the method. I have mocked that class and I expect it to return the stubbed result. It actually works using `doReturn`, but it returns the same data every time. I want it to return different data and I want to be able to specify what it should be.

I tried using 'doReturn - when' and it works, but I can't make it return a different result. I don't know how to do this.

I also tried using 'when - thenReturn' which was the solution I found here on StackOverflow. With that, I could specify o get different responses every time I called the same method.

Problem is that I get a compilation error

> The method XXX is undefined for the type `OngoingStubbing<MyClass>`

```
JSONArray jsonArray1 = { json array1 here };
JSONArray jsonArray2 = { json array2 here };

// Works but return the same jsonArray1 every time:
MyClass MyClassMock = mock(MyClass.class);
Mockito.doReturn(jsonArray1)
        .when(MyClassMock).getMyValues(any(List.class), any   (String.class), any(String.class),
                any(String.class),
                any(String.class));

// Does not work:
when(MyClassMock).getMyValues(any(List.class),
       any(String.class), any(String.class),
       any(String.class),
       any(String.class)).thenReturn(jsonArray1, jsonArray2);


// Compile error:
// The method getMyValues(any(List.class), any(String.class), any (String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class)) is undefined for the type OngoingStubbing<MyClass>
```

I get compile error:

> The method getMyValues(any(List.class), any(String.class),
>   any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class)) is undefined
>   for the type OngoingStubbing

Answer (score 2):

For normal mocks you can use something like this:

```
when(mockFoo.someMethod())
            .thenReturn(obj1, obj2)
            .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Fail"));
```

If you are using spy() and the doReturn() instead of the when() method:

what you need to return different object on different calls is this:

```
doReturn(obj1).doReturn(obj2).when(this.client).someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put the mock + its method inside the `when`:

```
when(MyClassMock.getMyValues(any(List.class),
           any(String.class), any(String.class),
           any(String.class),
           any(String.class))
    .thenReturn(jsonArray1)
    .thenReturn(jsonArray2);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put the mocked method inside the when:

```
when(MyClassMock.getMyValues(any(List.class),
       any(String.class), any(String.class),
       any(String.class),
       any(String.class)).thenReturn(...);
```

Also if you want more controll about what is returned (e.g. depending on the input parameters of the method you should use an [Answer](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) instead of just returning values.

So this would be a better solution I think:

```
when(MyClassMock.getMyValues(any(List.class),
       any(String.class), any(String.class),
       any(String.class),
       any(String.class)).thenAnswer(new Answer<JSONArray> {/*Add implementation here*/});
```

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615330/mockito-doanswer-vs-thenreturn) can help using the Answer class of Mockito.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks everyone for all the answers. 

I changed like you suggested but i am now getting an error saying 
"The method thenReturn(JSONArray) is undefined for the type JSONArray" on the .thenReturn statment.

I have not tried the solution with "new Answer<JSONArray>" as i need to learn how to use Answer first. Also I don't have any implementation. I just want to return a JSON object.

Best regards / Jan

Comment: This sounds like the compiler expected a different return type from the method getMyValues(...). Are you shure you use the correct return type here?

Answer (score 0):

This last suggestion worked!

Mockito.doReturn(obj1).doReturn(obj2).when(this.client).someMethod();

Thanks everyone for helping!
/ Jan