# Should I use doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()) or ArgumentCaptor for testing a delete method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to create a unit test for this delete method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void delete(UUID uuid) {
        final Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(EMPLOYEE));
        employeeRepository.delete(employee);
}
```

I have confused about using a proper way for testing (`employeeRepository.delete(employee)`) this method. I can use `doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg())` or `ArgumentCaptor`, or maybe none of them is a proper method. So, how should I test this delete method (`employeeRepository.delete(employee)`)?

Comment: ArgumentCaptor is used to capture an argument used to call a stubbed method and verify/check the captured argument.

Comment: What is your test scenario and what are you trying to test?

Comment: @Barracuda Yes, I know. But for this scenario, maybe `ArgumentCaptor` is a proper option to test `delete` method. By the way, I want to test `delete` method. Any help pls?

Comment: @Barracuda Amigo? Any reply pls?

Comment: if I don't know the scenario you are testing, I can't help you. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615330/mockito-doanswer-vs-thenreturn to understand why doAnswer might be helpful. If you want to test that your delete method was called with a specific argument, then you might want to use ArgumentCaptor to get the argument and that a proper one was used. DoAnsweri s used for stubbing, not for verification.

Comment: I said the scenario many times, but I think you did not read my last comments. Then as far as I see, you suggest to use `ArgumentCaptor`, right?

Comment: I am not suggesting anything because I am still missing your testing scenario. "Testing method A" is not a scenario. One example might be testing that method A throws exception B when called with input X. You should understand when to use which and decide based on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to test that  employeeRepository.delete(employee) is called with proper argument and you have stubbed employeeRepository.delete and findByUuid, then there should be verification methods available for your librariy(mockito has documentation on verification on their site).

Comment: I use the following scenario: When a valid employee is found, then delete it.

Comment: Is employeeRepository a mock?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you want to test that the stubbed value returned from employeeRepository.findByUUID(...) is passed into employeeRepository.delete(...). Then you can use mockito's verification capability. Read the documentation about verification.

Comment: Then I use verify method. Thanks a lot.