# How do I manipulate an argument with mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using junit to run a few unit tests. One of these calls a method in an object that I mock using mockito like;

```
@Mock
private MyClass myClass;
```

I then set up mockito to do something like

```
Mockito.when(myClass.foo(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(bar);
```

Now myClass.foo actually takes another one of my classes (say class Person) as an argument and what I would like to do is something like this

```
Mockito.when(myClass.foo(Person parson)).thenDo(person.setName("Name")).thenReturn(bar);
```

That is of course pseudo code but I hope it illustrates what I am trying to do. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `thenAnswer` or its twin `doAnswer` method.

See [Mockito : doAnswer Vs thenReturn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36627077/1570854)

> You should use `thenReturn` or `doReturn` when you know the return value at the time you mock a method call. This defined value is returned when you invoke the mocked method.
>
> `Answer` is used when you need to do additional actions when a mocked method is invoked, e.g. when you need to compute the return value based on the parameters of this method call.

If your answers become too complicated, consider using a fake instead of a mock.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if your goal is to set field of Person object you can do that before or after the line:

```
Mockito.when(myClass.foo(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(bar);
```

doAnswer() would help do operations based on input, but operations would be performed on copy of arguments not the original arguments.